# I have a white space underneath my footer and I can't find the reason why

Tags: html, css

There is a white space under my footer which I cannot seem to fix. Hoping that one of you people can help me out here.
I have tried to set all the margins to 0 but at this point I don't know anymore.

Beside the white space under the footer I am also open to suggestions or tips on how to improve my coding.

```js
/*
MenuToggle 
*/
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
                    $('nav').toggleClass('active')
                })
})
/*
Current year in footer 
*/
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
.clearfix::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 540px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 720px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 960px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1140px;
    }
}
/*  ----------  */
/* COL-JUSTGRID */
/*  ----------  */

/* Voor mobiele telefoons */
[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;  
}
/* Extra kleine modellen (Telefoons, 600px en minder) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  /* GRID voor Extra kleine modellen */
  .col-xs-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-xs-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-xs-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-xs-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-xs-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-xs-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-xs-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-xs-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-xs-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-xs-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-xs-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-xs-12 {width: 100%;}
  .xs-hide {display: none;!important}
} 
/* Kleine modellen (portrait tablets en grote telefoons, 600px en meer) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  /* GRID voor Kleine modellen */
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
  .s-hide {display: none;!important}
} 
/* Medium modellen (landschap tablets, 768px en meer) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {   
  /* GRID voor Medium modellen */
  .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
  .m-hide {display: none;!important}
} 
/* Grote modellen (laptops/desktops, 992px en meer) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {   
  /* GRID voor Grote modellen */
  .col-l-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-l-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-l-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-l-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-l-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-l-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-l-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-l-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-l-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-l-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-l-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-l-12 {width: 100%;}
  .l-hide {display: none;!important}
} 
/* Extra grote modellen (Grote laptops en desktops, 1200px en meer) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {   
  /* GRID Extra grote modellen */
  .col-xl-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-xl-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-xl-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-xl-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-xl-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-xl-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-xl-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-xl-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-xl-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-xl-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-xl-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-xl-12 {width: 100%;}
  .xl-hide {display: none;!important}
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box !important;

}
html { 
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: mr-eaves-modern, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* Header section */
header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
header .hbrand {
    float: left;
    font-family: bebas-neue, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 100px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
header nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
header nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
header nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li a {
    padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
header nav ul li a.active,
header nav ul li a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu-toggle {
    float: right;
    line-height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 992px){
    header {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    }
    header nav {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
        background-color: #fff;
        top: 100px;
        left: -100%;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    header nav.active {
        left: 0;
    }
    header nav ul {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }
    header nav ul li a {
        line-height: 75px;
    }
    .menu-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
}

/* Main section */
main {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Footer section */
footer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
.copyright, .copyright a {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    color: white;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 50;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* Backgrounds */
.b-white {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.b-black {}
.b-darkgray {
    background-color: #191919;
}
.b-gray {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>New website</title>
    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/justgrid.css" type="text/css"><!-- JustGrid -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme.css" type="text/css"><!-- Theme stylesheet-->
    <!-- Javascripts -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a9b20b17fc.js"></script><!-- Fontawesome icons -->
</head>
    
<body class="b-gray">
<!-- header -->    
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hbrand">Logo</div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars" aria hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- Main -->  
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-s-12 col-m-3">
                <div class="container b-white">
                    "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"

Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."

1914 translation by H. Rackham
"On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-s-12 col-m-9">
                <div class="container b-white">
                    Content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<!-- Footer --> 
<footer class="b-white">
    <div class="container">
        <div>First footer part</div>
    </div>
</footer>
<div class="copyright b-darkgray">
    <div class="container">
        <div>© Kopierechten 1999-<span id="year"></span> - <a href="#">Disclaimer</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/theme.js"></script>
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove white space below footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188161/remove-white-space-below-footer)

Comment: try adding `margin: 0` to `html` in css

Comment: it looks like the snippet does not reporodce the issue you have?

Comment: it does. Maybe its just because of the way its embedded. But there is a small visible white line under the footer.
Also tried adding margin: 0 to html in css but i allready had tried that and i have elemenated all the extra code that was not needed.

Comment: Are you sure that's not the border on your browser window? The snippet doesn't have a white line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's coming from the padding your are applying to the link in the copyright section. Since it's an inline element the padding will not contribute to the layout and will overflow from the top and bottom create that white line.

Add `inline-block` to that element to avoid the issue

```
.copyright a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Full code:

```js
/*
MenuToggle 
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('active')
  })
})
/*
Current year in footer 
*/
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.clearfix::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}


/*  ----------  */


/* COL-JUSTGRID */


/*  ----------  */


/* Voor mobiele telefoons */

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Extra kleine modellen (Telefoons, 600px en minder) */

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  /* GRID voor Extra kleine modellen */
  .col-xs-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-xs-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-xs-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xs-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-xs-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xs-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-xs-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-xs-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xs-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-xs-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-xs-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .xs-hide {
    display: none;
    !important
  }
}


/* Kleine modellen (portrait tablets en grote telefoons, 600px en meer) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  /* GRID voor Kleine modellen */
  .col-s-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-s-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-s-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-s-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-s-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-s-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-s-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-s-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-s-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-s-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-s-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-s-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .s-hide {
    display: none;
    !important
  }
}


/* Medium modellen (landschap tablets, 768px en meer) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* GRID voor Medium modellen */
  .col-m-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-m-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-m-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-m-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-m-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-m-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-m-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-m-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-m-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-m-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-m-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-m-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .m-hide {
    display: none;
    !important
  }
}


/* Grote modellen (laptops/desktops, 992px en meer) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  /* GRID voor Grote modellen */
  .col-l-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-l-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-l-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-l-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-l-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-l-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-l-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-l-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-l-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-l-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-l-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-l-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .l-hide {
    display: none;
    !important
  }
}


/* Extra grote modellen (Grote laptops en desktops, 1200px en meer) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* GRID Extra grote modellen */
  .col-xl-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-xl-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-xl-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xl-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-xl-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-xl-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xl-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-xl-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-xl-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xl-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-xl-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-xl-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .xl-hide {
    display: none;
    !important
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: mr-eaves-modern, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Header section */

header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

header .hbrand {
  float: left;
  font-family: bebas-neue, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

header nav ul li a {
  padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

header nav ul li a.active,
header nav ul li a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-toggle {
  float: right;
  line-height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  }
  header nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 100px;
    left: -100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  header nav.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  header nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }
  header nav ul li a {
    line-height: 75px;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* Main section */

main {
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Footer section */

footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.copyright,
.copyright a {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  color: white;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 50;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.copyright a {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Backgrounds */

.b-white {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.b-black {}

.b-darkgray {
  background-color: #191919;
}

.b-gray {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>New website</title>
  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/justgrid.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- JustGrid -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- Theme stylesheet-->
  <!-- Javascripts -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a9b20b17fc.js"></script>
  <!-- Fontawesome icons -->
</head>

<body class="b-gray">
  <!-- header -->
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="hbrand">Logo</div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars" aria hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Main -->
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-s-12 col-m-3">
          <div class="container b-white">
            "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
            happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves
            or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
            exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?" Section 1.10.33
            of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati
            cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque
            nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint
            et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat." 1914 translation by H. Rackham "On the other hand, we
            denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs
            to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled
            and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur
            that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse
            pains."
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-s-12 col-m-9">
          <div class="container b-white">
            Content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="b-white">
    <div class="container">
      <div>First footer part</div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <div class="copyright b-darkgray">
    <div class="container">
      <div>© Kopierechten 1999-<span id="year"></span> - <a href="#">Disclaimer</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/theme.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out about modern clearfix. It works perfectly.

```
/* modern clearfix */
.classname_of_the_footer_element:before,
.classname_of_the_footer_element:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    line-height:0;
}
.classname_of_the_footer_element:after {
    clear:both;
}
```

In your case,

```
/* modern clearfix */
.copyright:before,
.copyright:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    line-height:0;
}
.copyright:after {
    clear:both;
}
```

adding this will do the trick. Check the results here - https://jsfiddle.net/94ze0skL/

Refer [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/relative-position-and-whitespace-at-bottom-below-footer/33785/2) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the styles of the footer on the `a` tag. Or just add `display: inline-block` to the `a` tag in the footer separately.

```css
.copyright {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  color: white;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 50;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.copyright a {
  color: white;
}
```